# ElasticSearch Java API TransportClient address in configuration file

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Given the application using ElasticSearch's JavaAPI TransportClient, i want to use native `elasticsearch.yml` (resolved by `InternalSettingsPreparer`) config file in class path to connect to cluster via transport.

For now i have the following contents:

```
cluster:
  name: elasticsearch # would be ${es.cluster.name}

network:
  host: localhost 
  transport_address: localhost:9301 # would be ${es.network.trasport}
```

and the initialisation of client:

```
TransportClient client = new TransportClient();
```

Which gives me exception:

```
13/12/16 14:04:40 INFO elasticsearch.plugins: [Hanna Levy] loaded [], sites []
org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: No node available
```

But when I add the following line

```
client.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("localhost", 9301));
```

things begin to work as expected.

So i wonder, whether is there a way to configure transport addresses from standard configuration file format and not re-invent the wheel by having a config file for config file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use transport.tcp.port Should look like the following:

```
 cluster:
   name: elasticsearch # would be ${es.cluster.name}

 network:
   host: localhost 
   transport: 
     tcp:
       port: 9301 # would be ${es.network.transport.tcp.port}
```

Also, I typically use the following format for my elasticsearch.yml file

```
cluster.name=elasticsearch
network.host=localhost
network.transport.tcp.port=9301
```

Comment: doesn't work still: org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: No node available
 at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:212)

Comment: I tested this locally and had a similar error until I modified the port to be a range: 9300-9400 I checked the documentation and the port setting should be a range - http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-transport.html It defaults to 9300-9400 which should be sufficient for you. So you can either put the 9300-9400 value or remove it since you are using the default already.

Comment: Still no success in that: 

// java code:
TransportClient client = new TransportClient();
client.admin().cluster().prepareState().execute().actionGet();

// config/elastisearch.yml
cluster.name: elasticsearch
network.host: localhost
network.transport.tcp.port: 9300-9400

still gives "No node available" exception

P.S. es-0.90.7

Comment: This version of elasticsearch.yml file needs to go in the src/main/resources folder of your Java project. See - http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/client.html I am also using 0.90.7.

Comment: it's there and it doesn't change the situation :(

Comment: @javanna do you think it's a good idea to have them in configuration file or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I always called

```
Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
                .put("cluster.name", "mycluster")
                .put("client.transport.sniff", true).build();

        // now try to connect with the TransportClient
        Client client = new TransportClient(settings)
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(
                        "localhost", httpPort));
```

which resulted in:
org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: No node available

In the logs I found:
bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9210]}, publish_address {inet[/172.00.71.128:9200]}

But I got a
[transport.netty] [Sabra] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x0fd1380f, /127.0.0.1:53090 => /127.0.0.1:9300]], closing connection
java.io.IOException: Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen

After searching for a fix to this quite a long time myself I finally found this working for me:

When you call `http://localhost:9200/_cluster/state` I noticed that only my local IP address was bound, not the localhost loopback.

Changing my TransportAddress configuration to

```
InetAddress IP = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
client = new TransportClient(settings)
    .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(IP.getHostAddress(), 9300));
```

finally solved my issue. Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is, no, Elasticsearch does not have a way to configure a default set of network addresses to join when using the transport client.

However, it's rather simple to add support for this while still piggybacking on the default configuration loading etc by adding it to anywhere you'd like in the configuration. For example, in `elasticsearch.yml`:

```
transport.client.initial_nodes: ["localhost:9301"]
```

can be loaded by the following code which includes some extra parsing for the optional port number:

```
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.InetSocketTransportAddress;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TransportClient client = new TransportClient();

        for(String host: client.settings().getAsArray("transport.client.initial_nodes")) {
            int port = 9300;

            // or parse it from the host string...
            String[] splitHost = host.split(":", 2);
            if(splitHost.length == 2) {
                host = splitHost[0];
                port = Integer.parseInt(splitHost[1]);
            }

            client.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(host, port));
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```